# vb.net object type is collection of T

Tags: vb.net, collections, typeof

I have a generic function for ToString. It work good except for collection.

I search a way to create an exception : if the item is a list of object (something from System.Collections.Generic or an array), it should do a ToString for each element of the list.

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder(String.Format("{1}<{0}>", Me.GetType.FullName, System.Environment.NewLine))
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    For Each item In [GetType]().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        sb.Append(String.Format("[{0} = {1}] ", item.Name, item.GetValue(Me)))
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

It can be a list(of string) or string() or stack(of string) or any else kind of any kind of list of object.

Comment: Try to cast to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: maybe a code sample? may be useful.